# How to add offset to shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11

I was trying to create a single slab of memory for my matrix class because `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` was not giving the performance I wanted. So I decided to use single 1d array. So I thought of using shared_ptr of double for this.

To declare the variable I did:

`std::shared_ptr<double> matrix;`

To allocate memory for declared shared pointer I did:

`matrix = std::make_shared<double []> (row*col);`

Now to access the element to assign something to specific location in matrix :

`*(matrix + r*col + c) = 0.0;`

This gives me error saying

`error: no match for 'operator+' ( operand types are 'std::shared_ptr' and 'size_t ')

I thought we could use `+` on pointer. Why is it not letting me add scalar value to the pointer?

Comment: Why not just use `std::vector<double> matrix(row*col)`?

Comment: I would not expect that doing your own 2D math would be faster than `vector<vector<...>>`.

Comment: Use `matrix.get() + ...`. Or do what Nathan said above.

Comment: just as Jason C said, use `*(matrix.get() + r * col + c)` and .. voila, it will work

Comment: @MarkRansom wouldn't it be like comparing deque vs vector (http://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2012/12/cpp-benchmark-vector-list-deque.html) The graph there shows `at least for fill` vector doing better then deque` for size of 8 ... considering 2d vector as deque

Comment: @NathanOliver I think that is good point

Comment: Mark: vector<vector<double>> would for sure be slower due to the double indirection. However a simple vector<double> with correct offset calculation as proposed by NathanOliver is fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) is not a pointer, it's a class that encapsulates a pointer. That's why the `operator +` does not work on `shared_ptr`

If you had a regular pointer (`double* matrix`) then everything would be fine. You can get the regular pointer out of `shared_ptr` by using [get()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/get)

This changed your code into `*(matrix.get() + r*col + c) = 0.0;`

An equivalent expression is `matrix.get()[r*col + c] = 0.0;`

Another way to store the data (if you don't want it shared) it is to use a [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
std::vector<double> matrix(row * col);
matrix[r * col + c] = 0.0;
```

using a vector presents an advantage when you have a debug build, the `operator []` can check if the expression `r * col + c` returns an index that's invalid (for example if r >= col)

Comment: thank you for the answer .. for some reason I forgot std::shared_ptr not necessarily a pointer but actually are wrapper around the pointer :/